# '20-byte hash required' message on Mercurial commit

Tags: mercurial, dvcs, tortoisehg, mercurial-extension

I was experiencing an issue with a repository that would error with a 'No Node' message when viewing in Tortoise Workbench. So, I upgraded to TortoiseHg 2.5.1 and am now receiving '20-byte hash required' when i try to commit. I was able to commit before. I couldn't find anything about this message on the web. Any ideas what it means?

Comment: Sounds like a TortoiseHg bug... Do you get a stack trace along with that message? The TortoiseHg bug tracker is here: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/?kind=bug&status=open

Comment: Thanks. Submitted bug to the tortoise project.

Comment: Link to bug: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/2198

Comment: Submitted a bug to the Mercurial bugtracker. http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3694

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a line feed in the branch name. Not sure how this happened though.  This confused Mercurial's branch cache, causing this error. In Mercurial 2.4, this is explicitly disallowed.

For more info, see link on Mercurial bug tracker - https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=3694

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your repository is corrupt. Open a command prompt, navigate to your repository and run `hg verify`. If you see any errors, you should consider cloning the repository afresh (assuming that you had cloned this repository from some central server).

Comment: Tried an hg verify and received no errors. Just a display of changesets, manifests, revisions and files. Anything else to try?

Comment: Was there a particular changeset that TortoiseHg Workbench had complained about?

Comment: No. I didn't see any reference to a changeset in the bug report.

Comment: Tried a reclone. Looked promising until I tried a commit. Same issue.

Comment: did you see any warnings or informational messages during the clone operation? Also, what extensions, if any, have you enabled in `mercurial.ini`?

Comment: Only using tortoisehg. only settings there is postpull=update and closeci=true. No warnings or informational messages during clone. Runs perfectly.

Comment: can you try commenting out `closeci=true`? I am admittedly shooting in the dark here, but `closeci` is associated with the action of committing your changes and you are seeing problems when you try a commit

Comment: Is there another machine that you can test a clone and commit on?

Comment: Interesting. The clone worked and I can do a commit. However, when I try to do a Hg Workbench from Tortoise, I get the 'No Node' error I was getting in the first place. Found out I was running a older version of Tortoise and Mercurial on new machine. Upgraded to Tortoise 2.5.1 and now get the 20 byte hash required message on commit or workbench. HG verify shows no errors.

Comment: You may have stumbled upon a regression. If there's some public repository that you can reproduce the problem with, it would help the TortoiseHg team fix the [bug](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/2198) that you had created for this.